# Refund for foreign purchase is less than amount spent. Will credit card company refund difference?

Tags: credit-card, refund

I recently made a credit card purchase at a Japanese shopping website. When I looked at my statement, the amount was in dollars (converted from Japanese yen). Later, I cancelled my order and was refunded the same amount in yen, but because of the exchange rate, the amount (in dollars) I was refunded (-$10) is **less than** the amount (in dollars) I spent ($12). Both transactions appear on my statement. Will my credit card company refund me the difference ($2) if I ask?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to know without asking them.  That said, I wouldn't expect them to.

Comment: Would you be happy if, had the rate drifted the other direction, they captured the profit? It's both of nothing, and it's easier for everyone if the credit card company just moves the money without trying to compensate for it speculate upon rate shifts.

Comment: If they refund that, there would be a way to get rich fast - Buy and cancel, buy and cancel, etc. every win is yours, every loss is reimbursed... it would be riskless currency trading. It can't work.

Answer (score 2):

Generally as a good will the card company may give you the credit for 2usd.

There is no harm in trying.

Comment: Just that $2 is really not enough to even bother, see related questions. :-)

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is not likely. You entered a transaction where you purchased yen with your dollars, then used the yen to purchase the items. Later, when  canceling the order, the yen transaction purchased dollars. Foreign currency prices change constantly. The credit card company (bank) isn't responsible for the difference in price changes between currencies. If you were to cross the border to another country (say Mexico, Canada), attempt to purchase an item with USD, the vendor MAY accept your USD at a specific exchange rate for that day. Were you to re-visit the next day and return the item, a different exchange rate would be in effect and you would be refunded accordingly.

Comment: Many credit cards also tack on a 3% foreign transaction fee on the amount of the purchase. In the best of all possible worlds, the OP will be charged the 3% on the difference between the purchase price and the return price. Possibly, the fee will charged only on the purchase price and not on the return price, but I wouldn't be surprised if the fee is charged both on the purchase as well as the return. After all, both are "foreign currency transactions" even though one is a debit and one a credit to the credit card company.

Comment: Good point- of course there are fees, not to mention spreads (buy/sell), etc.